# htaccess rewrite by making friendly url will not work

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to make my url from this:

**www.domain.com/view.php?id=15**

To ths:

**www.domain.com/watch/15**

My code in htaccess is as follows:

```
  Options -Indexes
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^watch/([^/]+) view.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Now if I go to www.domain.com/watch/15 it loads the content but without any js, css because in this case it looks for css and js under /watch folder which doesnt exist..

How do I make this option to work properly? I dont want to create watch folder and copy paste css and js so it will embed properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the base tag to the `head` section of html to fix the css/js problem.

```
<base href="http://www.yousite.com" />
```

Then your rules will work fine. I modified them a little as well for good measure.

```
  Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^watch/([^/]+)/? view.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```